# Can excludeFromRecents conflict with anything else? Is there alternative?

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-lifecycle

Hi I have tested excludeFromRecents="true" in a new empty app. It works. When I test it in my app, it works inconsistently. Sometimes it works, or sometimes it works only when I select another app. So it only gets removed from recent apps list when I click recent apps list when I'm in another app. If I do click recent apps from my app, I see it... Any idea why this behaviour is happening?

`<activity
            android:name=".activity.GetStartedActivity_"
            android:excludeFromRecents="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"/>`

In this case, this activity is still visible when recent apps is clicked. Using a 4.4.4 device

Also, I can see some apps are just displaying a black screen while the app stays present in recent apps list. Is this achieved by displaying a layout when onPause is triggered?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: 1. What do you mean by 'empty' app?
2. `excludeFromRecents` is a property of Activity
3. Post some code

Comment: by empty app, I just mean, a brand new empty, hello world project.  Posting some code wouldn't help, I'm just adding excludeFromRecents="true" in the manifest for the activities I'm wanting to hide...

Answer (score 0):

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);
```

called in onCreate (before setContentView) does what I need.